# Adding missing commits to git-svn converted repository

Tags: git, svn

### My scenario:

Project was converted from SVN to Git (via somewhat older version of `git-svn`):

SVN branches were converted to branches:

```
for branch in `git branch -r`; do
    git branch $branch refs/remotes/$branch
done
```

SVN tags were converted to tags:

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/tags | while read r; do
   sha1=$(git rev-parse $r)

   # stuff for formatting of committer, etc

   git tag ... $sha1

   # Remove the tags/* ref
   git update-ref -d $r
done
```

### Problem:

There were a handful of commits and tags that were committed to SVN before we fully switched over to Git.

**How do I get just those commits and tags added to the Git repo?**

I've tried doing `git svn init`, `git svn fetch`, but it seemed to be repeating the whole process - but I obviously need the git commits to be the same otherwise I've created a disjoint branch.l

Comment: Have there been commits and fixes to the git repo since the conversion?

Comment: @TriskalJM Yes, but not in any way that should create a divergent branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `git svn rebase` to pull in new commits.